# Second material not showing in the glhudsprite

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-7, glscene

I try to show an image in a TGLHudSprite in some odd way...

Here is my try..

i have a material library and a hudsprite...

```
myMatlib: TGLMaterialLibrary
mySprite: TGLHudSprite
```

next i create this objects...

```
myMatlib:= TGLMaterialLibrary.Create(self);
mySprite:= TGLHudSprite.CreateAsChild(MainScene.Background);
mySprite.Material.MaterialLibrary:= myMatlib;
mySprite.Material.LibMaterialName:= '';
mySprite.position.x:= 512;
mySprite.position.y:= 384;
mySprite.visible:= true;
```

run it and logical mySprite shows nothing...
now i add a material... with this function..

```
function AddMaterial(aMatLib: TGlMaterialLibrary; aFileName, aMaterialName: string):  TGlLibMaterial;
begin
  result := aMatLib.Materials.Add;
  with result do
  begin
    with Material do
    begin         
      MaterialOptions := [moIgnoreFog, moNoLighting];
      Texture.Disabled := false;
      Texture.TextureMode := tmModulate;
      BlendingMode := bmTransparency;
      with FrontProperties do
        begin
          Ambient.SetColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
          Diffuse.SetColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
          Emission.SetColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
          Specular.SetColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        end;
      Texture.ImageClassName := 'TGLCompositeImage';
      if ExtractFileExt(aFileName) = '' then
        TGLCompositeImage(Texture.Image).LoadFromFile(aFileName + '.png')
      else
        TGLCompositeImage(Texture.Image).LoadFromFile(aFileName);
    end;
    Name := aMaterialName;
  end;
end;
```

so i add a material with...

```
AddMaterial(myMatlib,'c:\pic.png','pic');
```

and then i set the material in my hudSprite...

```
mySprite.material.libmaterialname:= 'pic';
```

Everything works fine for now...

The thing i want to do is to freeandnil my material library recreated again, add a different material with the same name 'pic' and show it in my hudsprite...

so i make this....

```
 FreeAndNil(myMatlib);
 AddMaterial(myMatlib,'c:\spic.png','pic');
 mySprite.material.libmaterialname:= 'pic';
```

With this i get nothing but only a black picture...

What i am doing wrong...?

Btw the material loaded correcty bcs in a second sprite i create and not setting any other material it shows the "pic" correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need do this again: 
mySprite.Material.MaterialLibrary:= myMatlib;
mySprite.Material.LibMaterialName:= 'myMaterialName';